# Detect if value was changed by jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
$('#inserted_advert_id').val(data['id']);
myFunction();
```

But I want to run `myFunction()` after input `#inserted_advert_id` will be changed. Now, when I run this script, input `#inserted_advert_id` is not changed (it is changed after myFunction() is execute).

How I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this would be to manually raise a `change` event when you set the `val()` of the element:

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.log('advert id was changed!');
}

$('#inserted_advert_id').on('change', function() {
  // any processing logic, if needed, goes here
  myFunction();
});

// somewhere else in your code base...
var data = { id: 'foo' }
$('#inserted_advert_id').val(data['id']).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="inserted_advert_id" />
```